# Why does the Gmail API return garbage data

Tags: python, gmail-api

I was trying to get user emails from `gmail api` using `get` method. But when it comes to conversation `message['snippet']` returns

```
 "snippet": "Hey buddy On Fri, Oct 21, 2016 at 5:46 PM Januka
 Samaranayake &lt;abc@gmail.com&gt; wrote: hello brother",
```

When I use, `parts[len(parts)-1]['body']['data']` it has a Base 64 string which decodes to,

```
Hey buddy <span[g&F#7F&W"#bV6&RfC&Vc&F6&RVv6!ͅɅ六խ&gt; wrote:<br][H\HXZ[][H[OHX\[^؛ܙ\[Y\YY[[YY^W'#Fb673&vVFR#FbF#&G"#g&7B##bBSRV6&RfC&Vc&f67&CRSt"StBb337fb33b33VG'&Ff7F'6b33"F&vWC%&#VG'&Ff7F'6fwCw&FS'#Fc&6VFR673&vVFR"7GS&&vW&&FW"VgC66626ƖCFFrVgCW#䆓77У&6VFSFcУ&6VFSР
```

How to avoid previous messages or only get the most recent message.

Comment: What do you mean by garbage data? Are you talking about the HTML entities?

Comment: "On Fri, Oct 21, 2016 at 5:46 PM Januka
 Samaranayake &lt;abc@gmail.com&gt; wrote: hello brother"

Comment: `&lt;abc@gmail.com&gt;` is correct. It would be written as `<abc@gmail.com>` on the Gmail site

Comment: Take a look at the question @cricket_007 posted. It's essentially what you'll have to do to get decode HTML entities. I'm presuming that the reason you're getting encoded data is a safety feature within gmail-api (don't quote me on it, it's just a guess).

Comment: @cricket_007 it doesn't answer my question or not even relevant.

Comment: Well, after you updated, no, it doesn't

Comment: Decoding the email message parts does not directly contain raw b64 data. You have to do a bit of massaging to get it to display properly. In Javascript land (you'll have to translate to python) that means doing the following:
utf8 = decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(b64encoded.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')))));